ICSharpCode TextEditorEx key cannot be null
I am trying to replace a ICSharpCode.TextEditor with a TextEditorEx control but immediately get a key cannot be null exception.
When I tried a example solution, I could not get around the NUnit reference missing. I tried getting this from NuGet but no joy.

I tried clearing and refreshing the NuGet cache. This has no effect.

Is there any documentation or example code that uses the TextEditor or TextEditorEx controls?
